# AsyncTask with ProgressDialgue: Shows only at end

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I want to have a progress spinner display before my AsyncTask starts to send a message to a server, and goes away when it times out or gets a response. I have used onPreExecute and onPostExecute, but the dialogue appears and disappears after the AsyncTask finishes so it looks like it hangs and then jumps back into action. I want the dialogue to appear before the AsyncTask starts, and disappears after the socket times out or gets a reply. Can anyone help?

Activity that calls AsyncTask:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        ...

            login = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.loginLoginButton);
            login.setEnabled(false);
            login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AsyncTCPStringSend aSend = new AsyncTCPStringSend("Login||" + username.getText().toString() + "||" + password.getText().toString(), true, getActivity(), "Connecting to Server", "Please wait...");
                    aSend.execute();
                    while(aSend.getResponse().equals("")){}
                    if(aSend.getResponse().contains("Good")) {
                        FileOutputStream out = null;
                        try {
                            out = getActivity().openFileOutput("User", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            String write = username.getText().toString() + "||" +
                                           password.getText().toString();
                            out.write(write.getBytes());
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            if (out != null)
                                try {
                                    out.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                        }
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        getActivity().finish();
                    } else {
                        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invalid login information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        t.show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

AsyncTask:

```
package com.wdi.wdiandroid.networking;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class AsyncTCPStringSend extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    String message = "";
    String response = "";

    Context c = null;
    String gateway = "";
    ProgressDialog progress = null;
    boolean show = false;
    String title = "";
    String main = "";

    /**
     * Basic AsyncTCPStringSend
    */
    public AsyncTCPStringSend(String mes) {
        message = mes + "\n";
    }

    /**
     * AsyncTCPStringSend with spinner
    */
    public AsyncTCPStringSend(String mes, boolean spinner, FragmentActivity activity, String head, String body) {
        message = mes + "\n";
        show = true;
        progress = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        title = head;
        main = body;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if(show) {
            progress.setTitle(title);
            progress.setMessage(main);
            progress.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            socket = new Socket();
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("75.83.255.167", 4999),5000);
            socket.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes());

            ByteArrayOutputStream writeBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int bytesRead;
            InputStream writeIn = socket.getInputStream();

            while((bytesRead = writeIn.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                writeBuffer.write(buffer,0,bytesRead);
                response += writeBuffer.toString("UTF-8");
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "Unknown HostException: " + e.toString();
            System.out.println(response);
        } catch (ConnectException e) {
            response = "ConnectException: " + e.toString();
            System.out.println(response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
            System.out.println(response);
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if(show && progress.isShowing())
            progress.dismiss();
    }

    public String getResponse() {
        if(response.length() == 0)
            return "";
        else {
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `getResponse()` on the `AsyncTask` from the main thread - so basically blocking the main thread with your 'while' loop, which is causing it to 'hang'.

Answer (score 0):

Your main thread is locked up in a while loop, constantly waiting for the `AsyncTCPStringSend` to return data via its `getResponse()`.  Refactor the main code to start your `AsyncTCPStringSend` then return.  Have your async task then send a message or otherwise notify your `Fragment` that the response is ready.

Comment: How would you notify the calling Activity?

Comment: You could use a custom `Message` sent by the async task and a `Handler` in the `Fragment`.  Or, if you wanted a simpler yet not as tidy approach: create a protected method in your `Fragment` which processes the response and call it directly from your `onPostExecute()` method.  That method is called on the UI thread, just like the `onClick` your `Fragment` defines.